# Having trouble with text alignment in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-forms-designer, text-alignment

So i'm trying to format the output of a listbox. Basically I want the name of the item left aligned and the cost of the item right aligned. Here is my ToString() method that i'm using:

```
 public override string ToString() {
     return String.Format("{0, -20}{1, 10:C2}", name, cost);
 }
```

Then here is a picture of what the resulting output is doing:

[image: listbox output]

Am I missing something simple here? From everything I've read this should format my output properly. I've read some stuff about using ListView instead however for the assignment I'm required to use a ListBox. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to used a fixed-width font or find a third-party control that supports right-alignment.

Comment: Change the font of the ListBox. Use a font with a fixed width (a.k.a. Monospaced font)

Comment: It seems, you should use *monospaced* (fixed-pitch, fixed-width, non-proportional) font like `Courier`, `Courier New`, `Lucida Console`, `Monaco`

Comment: Yup that was it! didn't even think about the font being the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the font of the control to something with a fixed-width.

```
listBox1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 10);

listBox1.Font = new Font("courier", 10);
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I figured it was something simple but I couldn't seem to find this information anywhere.